# Composer still includes .git directory with --prefer-dist

Tags: composer-php

I added mypackage to the repositories key in composer.json:

```
"repositories": {
    "packagist": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    "mypackage": {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "company_name/mypackage",
            "type": "drupal-module",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/company_name/mypackage",
                "reference": "master"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I run `composer require company_name/mypackage-master --prefer-dist`

The package does get downloaded but it still adds the .git directory.  I would like the package to download without the .git directory.  How would I accomplish this?  I only have a master branch and no releases in github.

Comment: As far as I know the `.git` directory is required so git can track it? If you delete it, it is no longer being tracked by git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted issue in composer issues [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6370). To fix the issue I did the following:

1. Add `composer.json` file to my package:

   ```
   {"name": "company_name/mymodule",
   "type": "drupal-custom-module",
   "description": "My description",
   "keywords": ["Drupal"],
   "license": "GPL-2.0+",
   "homepage": "https://github.com/company_name/mymodule",
   "support": {
     "issues": "https://github.com/company_name/mymodule/issues",
     "source": "https://github.com/company_name/mymodule"
   },
   "require": { }}
   ```
2. Update repositories to in `composer.json` file (not the module `composer.json` file)

   ```
     "repositories": {
     "drupal-packagist": {
         "type": "composer",
         "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
     },
     "my-package": {
         "type": "vcs",
         "url": "https://github.com/company_name/mypackage"
     }},
   ```
3. Run `composer require company_name/mymodule --prefer-dist`.